# How to find the rows uploaded via Load Data Infile command

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I am uploading a csv file via the LOAD DATA INFILE command in a bash script.
I need to find out how many lines of data was uploaded. I need to know this to compare with the number of lines in the csv.

This is to verify that all the data mentioned in the CSV file was uploaded. 
I am using a bash script to do this upload as this will excuted on bi-hourly  everyday.

How can I get the number of rows uploaded.

```
mysql  -u $_db_user -p$_db_password -D $_db --local-infile=1 <<EOF

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$_csv_directory/TempImport.csv'
into table TempImport
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
EOF
```